# Background Image of CSS is not showing

Tags: java, css, spring, vaadin, war

I have written a Java WebApp with Vaadin 14.8.0 and SpringBoot.
When I put the application in production mode and create a war file with the command "mvn clean package -Pproduction" and deploy it on my Wildfly, everything works normally. My CSS files are read and also activated.
However, the path I use in the css file for the background image is not found.

```
"background-image: url("/META-INF/resources/img/zac-bromell-QwrTnOlWAmI-unsplash.jpg");"
```

If I enter the path directly as url:

```
"http://localhost:8080/planyoureplaylist-1.0-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/resources/img/zac-bromell-QwrTnOlWAmI-unsplash.jpg"
```

I also get a 404 Not Found.

My css files are located in the root directory under `./frontend/styles`.
My image files can be found in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/img/`.

I also looked at my WAR file with WINRAR. Since I notice that I find the image files in the directory `WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\resources\img`, but in the whole folder structure not my css files.

To my surprise the background image was displayed normally when I started the application not yet via an external wildfly.

In reference to the following link https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/11015 I understand that it is a bug of vaadin. However, since I am on Vaadin 14.8.0 and the bug should be fixed with 14.6.2 I do not understand the problem.

Gladly point out if something else is needed to solve the problem.

About help I would be very happy.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files in `META-INF/resources` are published in the server root so your `META-INF/resources/img/zac-bromell-QwrTnOlWAmI-unsplash.jpg` file is available at `img/zac-bromell-QwrTnOlWAmI-unsplash.jpg` inside your context root. Your background image CSS should thus be `"background-image: url("img/zac-bromell-QwrTnOlWAmI-unsplash.jpg");"`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have assumed that I must specify the path from the starting point of my css files. That is not the case then. Where are the css files then stored?

Comment: @Zakon Have you checked https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/loading-resources#resource-cheat-sheet ?